# Can't install 'youtube to mp3' (ubuntu14.04)

Tags: 14.04, youtube, mp3

When i try to install 'youtube to mp3' in the software center

I get the following error:

```
the following packages have unmet dependencies:

youtube-to-mp3: Depends: libc6 (>= 2.14) but 2.19-0ubuntu6.6 is to be installed
                Depends: libgcc1 (>= 1:4.1.1) but 1:4.9.1-0ubuntu1 is to be installed
                Depends: libqt4-declarative (>= 4:4.7.0~rc1) but 4:4.8.5+git192-g085f851+dfsg-2ubuntu4 is to be installed
                Depends: libqt4-network (>= 4:4.6.1) but 4:4.8.5+git192-g085f851+dfsg-2ubuntu4 is to be installed
                Depends: libqtcore4 (>= 4:4.8.0) but 4:4.8.5+git192-g085f851+dfsg-2ubuntu4 is to be installed
                Depends: libqtgui4 (>= 4:4.8.0) but 4:4.8.5+git192-g085f851+dfsg-2ubuntu4 is to be installed
                Depends: libstdc++6 (>= 4.6) but 4.8.2-19ubuntu1 is to be installed
                Depends: libav-tools (>= 4:0.8.6-0ubuntu0.12.04.1) but 6:9.16-0ubuntu0.14.04.1 is to be installed
                Depends: libavcodec-extra-53 (>= 4:0.8.6ubuntu0.12.04.1) but it is not going to be installed
                Depends: libmp3lame0 (>= 3.99.3+repack1-1) but 3.99.5+repack1-3ubuntu1 is to be installed
```

when I run it in the terminal:

```
sudo apt-get install youtube-to-mp3
```

I get the folowing message:

```
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
   youtube-to-mp3 : Depends: libavcodec-extra-53 (>=4:0.8.6ubuntu0.12.04.1) but it is not installable
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

Comment: How are you installing it?

Comment: Please open a terminal and run `sudo apt-get install youtube-to-mp3`. Is there by any change a note about “broken packages” at the end of the

Comment: … terminal output of that command?

Comment: you're trying to install the package that is for Ubuntu 12.04LTS and as I see it depends on `libavcodec-extra-53` but Ubuntu 14.04LTS has `libavcodec-extra-54` in repos in other words I couldn't locate ppa with package `youtube-to-mp3` for 14.04LTS.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I resolve unmet dependencies after adding a PPA?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/140246/how-do-i-resolve-unmet-dependencies-after-adding-a-ppa)

Answer (score 2):

Well, I've got an alternative if you change your mind

```
sudo apt-get install youtube-dl
```

Using this you can download mp3 , video of your choice using -F to find the number format and -f *number* to download
eg :

```
youtube-dl -f 18 https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=anything
```

Answer (score 1):

The best way to get it installed is [given in the link](http://www.coyotus.com/viewtopic.php?id=951) or follow the steps.

```
sudo add-apt-repository http://www.mediahuman.com/packages/ubuntu
sudo apt-key adv --keyserver pgp.mit.edu --recv-keys D808832C7D19F1F3
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install youtube-to-mp3
```

Everything should go well and you would be having youtube-to-mp3 installed on your Ubuntu 14.04.

Please refer to [Are PPA's safe to add to my system and what are some “red flags” to watch out for?](/q/35629) for the potential dangers of using PPAs.

Comment: I doubt this addresses the dependency problems.

Comment: Hi @DavidFoerster i have practically tested it and there is no reason to give negative marketing based on your assumption.

Comment: Do you have the same package repositories set up as OP? If not, your personal experience is non-repeatable and moot for OP and I maintain, that PPA dependency problems are by far the most likely cause of OP's issue, not his method of installation.

Comment: @DavidFoerster Did you try the solution out by yourself, I respect what you do, but giving negative marking for things which is working and resolving issues for people is not a good idea, but at the same side negative marking de motivates people and you should correct people instead of giving them negative reviews.
I don't deny that you should not give negative markings, but it should be for the people who give totally irrelevant answers.
Again its your perspective at looking over the answers, but i am really not happy with the way it is moderated.

Comment: @DavidFoerster, Adding the package repo will install needed dependencies. Therefore, this is absolutely correct answer as well as this satisfy the question.